# Intellisense not working for cmake projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio for a cmake project (Rigid Body simulation, but that probably doesn't matter). My problem is that Intellisense does not work at all, meaning no autocomplete and no underlining of syntax errors. I checked the options menu (options -> Text Editor -> C++ -> advanced -> Intellisense) and Intellisense seems to be turned on, however I don't understand all the options exactly.

Pressing ctrl + space (autocomplete) the bottom bar says 'No additional information available (see 'Troubleshooting Intellisense in c++ projects' for further help)'. However Intellisense works well in a standdard c++ project, and searching for the mentioned term tells me to check my options menu.

Searching for my issue on Google I've found this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/how-to-enable-intellisense-for-makefile-projects?view=vs-2017 , but I can't follow its instructions further than step 3 since my Property Pages -> Configuration property does not contain an 'NMake' page (I only have a 'General' page).

Thanks for your help.

Some Detail that may be of use: 
Operating System: Windows 10, 1803, build 17134.285
Visual Studio: Community 2017, Version 15.8.6
CMake: Version 3.12.2

Comment: How did you created the CMake project? I tried to follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/creating-a-makefile-project?view=vs-2017 and right click the project name, choose 'Properties' and the 'NMake' tab is existing.

Comment: I opened them by opening the ALL_BUILD.vcxproj that cmake generated. I'v now tried to open them by using "project from existing code", but if I do that it messes up my folder structure and won't compile (Error C1189 #error:  "no tasking system enabled")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue and it turned out to be related to git - visual studio 2017 [has a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/332189/intellisense-not-working-with-git.html), which breaks Intellisense if the git repository is cloned through WSL. So if you are using git, try to clone the repository through visual studio.

Ah, and, in case you didn't know, with VS2017 you can just open the cmake directory through the "Open folder" feature - no need to generate the project files manually anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually was using wsl for cloning my git repository , so that may well have been the Problem. But beeing unable to solve the problem for a while I ended up switching to Clion as my editor (which worked flawlessly)